# Clothes dryer broken exhaust fan

Tags: dryer

I have an LG DLEX8000W. One fan blade on the exhaust fan broke off. The rest of the fan is fine and I got the small broken piece out. Is it safe to still use the dryer or must I replace the fan?

Comment: Whether the broken blade was from wear or your fault, it should be replaced as noted in both (current) answers. If you need help getting the nut off, please [ask a whole new question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about that and include clear, focused, well lit pics of the problem area.

Comment: Might be a left-hand thread, a parts site might mention that if it is. Or it might just have beastly threadlocker on it. But yes, ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Once one blade breaks off, others are often not far behind. Replace it. But it doesn't have to cost much, as it turns out to be a fairly common part.

Searching a bit finds "LG 5835EL1002A Dryer Blower Wheel Assembly" on lgparts.com for $75.95. Then plugging the part # into Amazon finds a [compatible part](https://amzn.to/3vC0kxB) for $19.90:

[image: dryer blower wheel]

There are a lot of things where I am a bit skeptical of Amazon (and similar marketplaces) but for this kind of thing I think it is fine, and I have replaced similar types of appliance parts that way. (And at other times gone to my local supplier and paid 2x because I absolutely had to have it the same day.)

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot to mention the broken blade was my fault. I was trying to remove the nut that holds the fan on so I could remove some clothes my daughter got sucked down the pipe. But unfortunately the nut won’t come off so I’m not sure I can fix it myself now anyway.

Comment: Why won't the nut come off?  Won't rotate?  Can't stop the shaft from rotating?

Answer (score 2):

A fan (or "blower wheel") missing a blade is unbalanced. That usually leads to further damage due to vibration and eccentric loading. Of course, it also does not move air as effectively.

So, not replacing the fan may lead to needing to replace the motor that drives it since it is direct drive (usually a far more expensive part.) It may also cause other failures from vibrating the machine in an unplanned-for way.

In addition, if one blade of a plastic fan broke off without some sort of "incident" (or Foreign Object Damage) it's likely that the other blades are suffering the same fatigue stress that the first blade to break off succumbed to, and will follow it shortly (perhaps accelerated by the extra vibration.)

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot to mention the broken blade was my fault. I was trying to remove the nut that holds the fan on so I could remove some clothes my daughter got sucked down the pipe. But unfortunately the nut won’t come off so I’m not sure I can fix it myself now anyway.